# ShellExecute opens html file in browser but behind the active window

Tags: delphi

Why this code opens the chrome behind the current application when chrome is already running and default browser. IE works ok.

```
  Result := ShellExecute(Application.MainForm.Handle, nil,
    StrPCopy(zFileName, FileName), StrPCopy(zParams, ''),
    StrPCopy(zDir, ''), SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
```

Comment: I belive it could depend on your Chrome settings. What happens when you try openning specific html by double-clicking on the file. Does it bring Chrome to the foreground if it was opened before? Also when you are opening the html from your application does it open a new Chrome window, a new broser tab or does it navigate one of the current tabs to show your file?

Comment: Use `SW_SHOWNORMAL`. You should also never call `ShellExecute` because it cannot report errors in a meaningful way. Use `ShellExecuteEx` instead. That said, in this instance, `CreateProcess` would be better since you don't need the shell to do anything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If `zFileName` is an HTML file or URL, you can't use `CreateProcess()` to launch it (unless you query the Registry/FileExt settings manually), you need to use `ShellExecute/Ex()`.  Only use `CreateProcess()` when you know the exact .exe path+file to launch.  Otherwise, let the Shell figure that out for you.  That is its job.

Comment: @Remy I read the params arg and assumed that the asker was starting executable. The weird StrPCopy confused me. `SEE` is the way forward.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If I had to guess, the OP is using `StrPCopy()` because he doesn't know how to use `PChar()` casts, or he needs to copy the values into buffers that are used later in code not shown here.  But either way, use `ShellExecuteEx()` if accurate error handling is required, yes. If he just needs to know whether an error happened, but not what the actual error is, the `ShellExecute()` is fine.